# How to use getSupportFragmentManager() in YoutubeBaseActivity?

Tags: android

I have a class that extends YoutubeBaseActivity and inside it i want to import getSupportFragmentManager() for setting the adapter. That adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The constructer of the adapter is:

```
public ViewPagerAdapterMovies(FragmentManager fm ,ArrayList<MovieCategoryParent> MovieCategoryTabTitles, int mNumbOfTabsumb) {

    super(fm);
    this.MovieCategoryTabTitles = MovieCategoryTabTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;


}
```

The main problem here is that i am not being able to use getSupportFragmentManager() to send in the adapter.